# Maven dependencies inside tar.gz file

Tags: maven, tar, build-dependencies

So I have the following tar.gz file in my repo with structure as:

```
> A.tar.gz
>     |
>     |____ a.tar.gz
>     |
>     |____ b.tar.gz
>              |
>              |_____ folderA
>              |
>              |_____ folderB
>                       |
>                       |______ jar1.jar
>                       |
>                       |______ jar2.jar
```

Now in my POM file for another project I would like to add the jar1 and jar2 as dependencies. So far I have the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>master</artifactId>
        <version>18.1</version>
        <type>tar.gz</type>
        <classifier>bin</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

This made the tar file available. I then tried to unpack as:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeTypes>tar.gz</includeTypes>
                        <includeArtifactIds>master</includeArtifactIds>
                        <outputDirectory>target/somefolder</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

However, on running the build, I still don't get the jars as dependencies. I am sure I am missing something , so any help appreciated!

Comment: wrong way...you should use the original jar with it's according groupId/artifactId/version of which it is produced by and never via such packaged/repackaged tar.gz files etc...

Comment: @khmarbaise Unfortunately, the tar is being produced by another team and I don't control their packaging. (we are trying to though but in the meantime if there is a way here ... )

Comment: If they creating the package those jar's should have been created as well so you can use them directly as dependency...you should not control the packaging of the other team just use the jar's as dependencies that's it.

Comment: the thing is that the jars are not available in NEXUS independently but as part of the tar file.

Comment: Make a request to the other team deploy on Nexus...I have my doubts about that, cause that means the other team has changed the defaults in a Maven build also into a bad direction...which makes working for others a pain.

Answer (score 0):

So you have JAR dependencies located inside another tar.gz dependency that you want in your project. So far so good, the problem is you're trying to:

1. Make the the first .tar.gz dependency available (OK)
2. Launch the build to unpack the jars (OK)
3. Add unpacked jar as dependencies *during the same build* (Not possible)

All in one run. That is not possible in Maven by design (to the best of my knowledge). Even if you did find a way to do it this way, that would over-complexify your build and break Maven design, probably leading to other issues.

You mentioned that you don't control the packaging of the other team and it seems you can't upload said dependencies on a Nexus repo either. What you can do is make the JAR dependencies available in your local repo prior to running your build by doing something like:

1. Download your tar.gz file and unpack it
2. Install the jar dependencies in your local Maven repo using commands like `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path/to/jar1.jar -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=jar1 -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar` with proper version, groupdId and artifactId for each jars (see the [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) for more details)
3. Now you can run your your original project only by mentioning your jar dependencies as `<dependency>`

With this you will manually install your jar dependencies in your Maven local repository, rendering them available to your project without needing a Nexus repository or further unpackaging.  You can perform step 1 and 2 manually or by creating another Maven project that you will have to run once before running your main project. To do so you can create a new project and use the maven-dependency-plugin as you already did coupled with the [maven-exec-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to run the `mvn install:install-file` command.

**Note this process must be done for every individual machine on which you will run your project.** As @khmarbaise mentioned, it's best to have your dependencies available directly through a repository manager such as Nexus without having to perform additional steps, but this *temporary* workaround should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I really dont like the idea of manual install on my local repo since it involves manual steps like downloading and I am not sure how this would turn out on a build server.

In any case, I think for now our main course of action is to escalate to the other team that they upload their jars separately in addition to their current packaging of tar file. Lets see how that goes ... 

Thanks for all your responses! (I am not sure if I should accept this answer or not ?)

Comment: My pleasure! As you wish for acceptance, if you think that it does provide a suitable answer to the initial problem you exposed -even though you finally chose another (better, I think) course of action- feel free to accept and/or upvote ;)